# A doubt about convergence in probability and almost sure convergence.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb E(X_1^2) \lt \infty.$ Show that $$\frac {2} {n (n + 1)} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j X_j \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb E(X_1)\ \ \text{as}\ n \to \infty.$$

**My Attempt** $:$ First we note that $$\left (\frac {2} {n (n + 1)} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j X_j \right ) - \mathbb E(X_1) = \frac {2} {n (n + 1)} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j \left [X_j - \mathbb E(X_j) \right ].$$ So in order to show the desired conclusion it is enough to show that $$\tag{*}\frac {2} {n (n + 1)} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} j \left [X_j - \mathbb E(X_j) \right ] \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 0.$$ Let $Y_n = X_n - \mathbb E(X_n), n \geq 1.$ Using [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma) it is enough to show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {Y_n} {n + 1}$ converges almost surely. By virtue of [Kolmogorov's two-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem) we need only to ensure whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb {Var} (Y_n)} {(n+1)^2} \lt \infty.$ Now $$\begin{align*} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb {Var} (Y_n)} {(n+1)^2} & = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb E (Y_n^2)} {(n + 1)^2} \\ & = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb {Var} (X_n)} {(n + 1)^2} \\ & \leq \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {\mathbb E (X_n^2)} {(n + 1)^2} \\ & = \mathbb E (X_1^2) \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {(n + 1)^2} \lt \infty\ \ (\text {identical distribution}) \end{align*}$$

Hence the result follows. $\square$

Is it fine what I argued above? Any suggestion for improvement would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you can simply show that the variance of the original sum converges to zero, and the convergence in probability follows from Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: @FredLi$:$ Wouldn't the variance of the original sum $\mathbb {Var} (X_1)\ $?

Comment: Should be of order $O(N^{-1})$ if you also square the scaling in front?

Comment: @FredLi$:$ Oh! Sorry. My bad! Then Markov's inequality does the job. But what I have shown is much stronger than what is being required. Right?

Comment: Yes, you have proved a.s. convergence.